# How to read numbers from file and take actions on them in java?

Tags: java, file

this is my file information:

`mahdi  aspanani    664 22.0
  ali   moghadasi   675 26.0`

I want to read this information from file and count 22.0 + 26.0

how can I do this in java?

Comment: read file like this https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-text-file-line-by-line/ split each line (string by space). do whatever you want to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First, open your file with a Scanner instance.
2. Read each line.
3. Split on spaces
4. Convert the fourth token to a double.
5. Add it to sum.
6. Continue until no more lines.

```
        Scanner input;
        String myFileName = "......";
        try {
            input = new Scanner(new File(myFileName)); 
            double sum = 0;
            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = input.nextLine();
                String[] vals = line.split("\\s+");
                sum += Double.parseDouble(vals[3]);
            }
            System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why use a Scanner and split it? The Scanner can do the splitting for you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the content of the file is structured like this:

```
<string> <string> <int> <summand 1> <string> <string> <int> <summand 2>
```

and none of the strings contains spaces and both summands are doubles, you can do the following:

```
try(BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))){
    String[] split=br.readLine().split(" ");
    double result=Double.parseDouble(split[3])+Double.parseDouble(split[7]);
    //do with it whatever you want
}catch(IOException e){
     e.printStackTrace();//or do something else or don't catch it and add it to the signature
}
```

Don't forget to put the name ofthe file instead of `filename`.

Comment: First, your method doesn't even compile.  Second when I fixed it, it didn't work.

Comment: @WJS Yes, I forgot a `)` Did you substitute `filename` with the name of the file?

Comment: Yes, I did.  You have multiple problems in your code.  You only read one line and you only split on one space.

Comment: @WJS the OP didn't mention multiple lines. Also the split method splits on as many occurences as possible.

Comment: Or do you mean that the seperator needs to be exactly one space? In the example of the OP, it is one.

Comment: Did you see the OPs example?  Two lines.  Second, even if it was one line, your solution would not work because you are only splitting on one space.  The OP has many spaces between the tokens.  See the example. I copied it directly put it in a file.

Comment: I do only see one line in `mahdi aspanani 664 22.0 ali moghadasi 675 26.0`. And I do not recognize more than one space between 2 tokens. Please tell me what I am missing. Is there another example?